# UIWebView leaking memory when loading .RTF files?

Tags: iphone, memory, memory-leaks, uiwebview, memory-management

Trying to load a .rtf file (2.4 MB) via webView like this:

```
 NSURL *docURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:docPath];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:docURL];
NSString *mimeType = //receiving proper mime type here
[webView loadData:data MIMEType:mimeType textEncodingName:@"utf-8" baseURL:docURL];
```

Loading such files leads to memory growth until app crashes. According to the Instruments memory growth continues even after complete deallocation of webView containing controller and webView itself. Being in other place of the application, using other app features, memory grows as if I'm still continuing browsing that .RTF file.

When closing/dismissing the controller I also do all things to deallocate WebView.
That is: mainWebview.delegate = nil; [mainWebview stopLoading]; , [mainWebview removeFromSuperview]; , [mainWebview release]; . 
(Even tried to do the following: [mainWebview loadHTMLString:@"" baseURL:nil]; )

What I see in instruments:
[image]

Does anybody have any ideas?
Thanks.

**EDIT:** I tested some large .RTF files (700 Kb - 2.4 Mb) on Safari, Chrome, Mercury browsers. Same thing happens everywhere, both simulator and device. I guess it's some bug in WebKit.

General situation: browsers use too much memory to process this kind of files. In 90% of cases just abnormally exit with "Crash" or "Low Memory" signal. If device handles peak memory usage when loading the file then memory drains back to normal, if not - it crashes.

Comment: That's not _technically_ a leak - it's just lots of memory being used. Does the static analyser give you any hints / clues? And is this on a real device or on the simulator? (The simulator sometimes gives odd results because it uses a different memory model. It's a simulator, not an emulator!)

Comment: Yep, almost the same thing happens on the simulator. (but app doesn't crashes, reaching some peak at 250-300 MB of live bytes, than releasing all, returning to normal.)
And static analyzer doesn't give me anything on this issue.

Comment: I mean I was using real device all the time.

Comment: If you've spent this long looking at this code and nothing is giving you a clue, perhaps you're looking in the wrong place? Is there any other code you suspect?

Comment: See my edit. You could also test some .RTF files on your device/simulator just for see what happens, if you'are interested.
I give up on this.

Answer (score 1):

I have also had several issues related to memory management when using `UIWebView`. [In my case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11815294/memory-leaks-with-uiwebview-and-javascript), I saw that behavior changed a lot depending on the way I loaded data into the web view. In your case, I have no solution, but based on my experience, maybe using:

```
NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:urlToYourRTFFile];
[webView loadRequest:req];
```

could make a difference

Comment: Same thing happens with loadRequest:. But thanks for response anyway.