# IOS8: UIWebView memory leak

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, uiwebview

**App description**:
I want to develop an app, which shows websites during set time. If time elapsed, it will load next website etc. It must be run as loop: if last website showed, it shoes first.

AppDelegate was not changed.
Storyboard has a Navigation Controller with this ViewController, which include UIWebView:

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>

@end
```

ViewController.m:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *mWebView;

@end

@implementation ViewController

NSMutableArray *mSites;
NSInteger mIndex;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);

    [super viewDidLoad];

    mSites = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [mSites addObject:@"http://www.bild.de"];
    [mSites addObject:@"http://www.spiegel.de"];

    [self setWebView];
    mIndex = -1;

    [self showNext];
}

- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden
{
    NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);

    return YES;
}

- (void)setWebView
{
    NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);

    [(self.mWebView.subviews)[0] setBounces:NO]; // No overscroll
    [self.mWebView setDelegate:self];
}

- (void)freeMemory
{
    NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);

    [self.mWebView loadHTMLString:@"" baseURL:nil];
    [self.mWebView stopLoading];
    [self.mWebView setDelegate:nil];

    [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];
    [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] setDiskCapacity:0];
    [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] setMemoryCapacity:0];
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad: (UIWebView *)webView
{
    NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);

    // Clear cache
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:0 forKey:@"WebKitCacheModelPreferenceKey"];
}

- (void)handleTimer: (NSTimer *)timer
{
    NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);

    [self freeMemory];
    [self setWebView];

    [self showNext];
}

- (void)showNext
{
    NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    // Loop
    if (mIndex < [mSites count] - 1) {
        mIndex++;
    } else {
        mIndex = 0;
    }

    NSString *site = [mSites objectAtIndex:mIndex];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:site];

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [self.mWebView loadRequest:request];

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:15
                                     target:self
                                   selector:@selector(handleTimer: )
                                   userInfo:nil
                                    repeats:NO];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning 
{
    NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.

    [self.mWebView reload];
}

@end
```

**Trouble**:
I use for testing iPad Air (A1474) and used two websites: http://www.bild.de and http://www.spiegel.de. After ca. 30 minutes crashes the app because of memory usage. The app use more than 300Mb.

I found more solutions to handle the memory leak trouble and integrate them in my code:

```
- (void)freeMemory
{   
    [self.mWebView loadHTMLString:@"" baseURL:nil];
    [self.mWebView stopLoading];
    [self.mWebView setDelegate:nil];

    [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];
    [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] setDiskCapacity:0];
    [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] setMemoryCapacity:0];
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad: (UIWebView *)webView
{   
    // Clear cache
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:0 forKey:@"WebKitCacheModelPreferenceKey"];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning 
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning]; 
    [self.mWebView reload];
}
```

But the solutions do not take effect. The app do not run longer than a hour.

Have somebody a solution how I can reach a app running time for at least a day for every?

Thanks in advance for suggestions.

Comment: if the app has no other purpose, it would be pointless and useless app and won't pass the review procedure ever. or is it just a personal project and general practice?

Comment: This is just personal project. For my use.

Comment: forget UIWebView on iOS 8. Checkout my answer here on WKWebView http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16514230/massive-memory-leak-in-ios-uiwebview