# Release memory after a webView

Tags: ios, swift, webview

I'm using the master-detail template of Xcode for my project. In the detail view controller I'm displaying a webView. When I go from the detail view controller back to the master view controller (the tableView) the webView doesn't release memory.

So when I click on multiple rows in the tableView and go to details, all the webViews that are loaded build up the memory and its never released. I tried to use this:

```
override func viewDidDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    webView.stopLoading()
}
```

But this only stops the loading and whatever was loaded before remains in memory. Any suggestions on how to release the memory?

Thanks!

EDIT:

I tried the solutions proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16514230/massive-memory-leak-in-ios-uiwebview) and the only thing I achieved is that my memory doesn't go much higher than 100 mb now. But my app starts at 10 mb and after displaying the webView a few times it goes up to about 100 mb. Here's what I've changed based on the proposed solutions:

```
override func viewDidDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    let requestURL = NSURL(string: "")
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: requestURL!)
    webView.loadRequest(request)
    webView.stopLoading()
    webView.delegate = nil
}
```

The problems is that the app still eats 10 times more memory than it should (from 10 mb to 100 mb). I also found other people that have the same problem, so I think this question is worth a good answer. And as @Dan said, those of us who are new at this need a solution in Swift.

Comment: not a duplicate, this question is for swift not objective-c.

Comment: @DanBeaulieu Irrelevant. A UIWebView is UIWebView. Language is a red herring.

Comment: @matt I see your point, however you may be viewing it from the point of view of an iOS guru. These things aren't quite as apparent to us newer people. Seeing solutions in-context are necessary in the beginning. Not to mention that google sees it differently entirely when someone Googling's the issue in the context of Swift. But I'll respect your call on this and wont argue any further, you've been here longer.